# Ustream video in WebView through html file doesn't autoplay

Tags: android, webview, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to play a LIVE streaming video (the example is the ISS live feed from Ustream). Simple as that. I tried with YouTube but it's too complicated meaning I have to get YouTube API and all that. The code works for me but there's only one problem: I need it to have autoplay enabled but it doesn't work. Any ideas on how to do that? Full code follows.

```
package com.splash.net.splashnet;

import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Display;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class Splash extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    WebView webView;

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;

    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/isslive.html");
   }
}
```

...and the HTML file...

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, height = device-height" />

    <style>
        iframe {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        }
</style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <iframe src="http://www.ustream.tv/embed/17074538?v=3&wmode=direct&autoplay=true"
    style="border: 0 none transparent;"
    frameborder="no"></iframe><br />

    </body>
</html>
```

I also tried different URLs just in case...

```
http://www.ustream.tv/embed/17074538
http://www.ustream.tv/embed/17074538?html5ui
http://www.ustream.tv/embed/17074538?wmode=direct
http://www.ustream.tv/embed/17074538?html5ui?wmode=direct
http://www.ustream.tv/embed/17074538?html5ui=1&autoplay=true
```

All I want is tap on the icon and get live feed. I'm working on API 19 (KitKat). Any information or other approavhes on the matter are welcome. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these attributes to the iframe:

```
<iframe webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen ...>
```

Comment: Android studio said "not allowed in here" for "webkitAllowFullScreen" and "mozallowFullscreen", used them anyway but no change. Besides, my problem is about autoplay attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```

Try to add this line to your WebView

And to your iframe

```
http://www.ustream.tv/embed/17074538?html5ui=1&autoplay=true"
```